# How can I create the same but independent dictionary structure many times in one line?

Tags: python-2.7

I have this one-liner below, but it creates 4 references to the **same** dictionary within the list. I want the same structure of the dictionary but created independently 4 times (as if you were using copy). How can I do this in one line using a similar approach (if possible)?

```py
sets = [{'reps': None, 'weightOverride': None}]*4
```

Using the above, modifying the key values of any dict in the list will change them all. I want them independent.

Answer (score 0):

Well now I feel stupid... I can just use:

```py
sets = [{'reps': None, 'weightOverride': None} for i in range(4)]
```